# Kinematics Problem (Differential Equation) : Particle moving in circle such that Radial acceleration=Tangential acceleration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, kinematics

> A particle is moving on a circle of radius R such that at every
>   instant the radial and tangential accelerations are equal in
>   magnitude.If velocity of the particle be $v_0$ at t=0,then what should be time for completion of half of the first revolution ?

I took $dv/dt=v^2/R$ and tried to solve the differential equation.But I cannnot understand how to take the limits of integration.Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac { dv }{ dt } =\frac { { v }^{ 2 } }{ r } \\ \frac { dv }{ { v }^{ 2 } } \quad =\quad \frac { 1 }{ r } \quad dt\\ \int { \frac { dv }{ { v }^{ 2 } }  } \quad =\quad \int { \frac { 1 }{ r } \quad dt } \\ \frac { -1 }{ v } \quad =\quad \frac { t }{ r } +C
$$

Now you solve for $C$ using the initial conditions:

$$
\\ \\ C\quad +\frac{1}{r}\times 0\quad =\quad \frac { -1 }{ { v }_{ 0 } } \\ C\quad =\quad \frac { -1 }{ { v }_{ 0 } } 
$$

Finally the answer is:$\\ \\ \frac { -1 }{ v } \quad =\quad \frac{1}{r}t-\frac { 1 }{ { v }_{ 0 } }  $

Or by rearranging you get:

$$
v\quad =\quad \frac { r{ v }_{ 0 } }{ r-{ v }_{ 0 }t } 
$$

Comment: I just edited now it's correct

Comment: Yes now its ok..thanks a ton :-)

Comment: Glad to help ^^, do you want me to solve for the time of half revolution?

Comment: Bousiff...lemme try first :-P

Comment: aha ok as you wish ^^

Comment: Ok i'm getting like $\frac{dt}{1/v_0-rt}=dx$,now integrating both sides...what should be limits for dx ...i.e the rhs?

Comment: Don't worry about limits just integrate and solve for the constant of integration(using initial conditions) just as I did in my answer otherwise take the limits from ${x}_{0}$ to some $x$ you know and do the same for $t$ P.S:If you want me to solve the question don't hesitate to ask ;)

Comment: I'm facing a problem at the end..I'm getting $(-1/r)ln(t-\frac{1}{v_0r})=x$..after that?

Comment: If the path is circular wouldn't $v(t) = r \frac{d\theta}{dt}$ where $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$?

Comment: Sanchayan look at Tucker's answer it's the the correct formula

Comment: I'm such a fool :-P..i got it now...silly mistake on my part..:-) thanks again @Tucker

Comment: Not a fool. With physical problems it is always important to think about the most natural coordinates. Polar coordinates are most suited for this problem.

Comment: Got it got it..and yahoo solved it..answer is $R/v_0e^{-\pi}$

Comment: @Tucker..well I agree :-)!!Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Are you sure that's the answer? (I got something different)

Comment: Oussama Bousiff Please provide your answer.As the correct answer is different.

Comment: He did not compute the constant part.